# Building a Vintage Car Microprocessor Controlled Climate Control System

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, control, control-system

First, let me just say that it has been over 50 years since I worked much in electronics and that was mainly using vacuum tubes so my question here is not so much to get any details but just to find out IF what I want to do is feasible. I hope I can explain this without boring everyone and if there is a more suitable group to post it in, please advise.

I am trying to re-create and modernize an A/C system for a specific make of vintage car to replicate the original factory installed unit but which can also be retrofit into a car that did not original have A/C.

There is a spacious trunk-mounted unit which is the heart of the A/C system and a relatively large dash control panel, in a zinc alloy casting, which has three knobs. The devices that these knobs turn in the original are massive '50s-era ceramic rheostats and switches which I want to replace using modern electronics both for the controls and for what they do in the trunk unit to adjust fan speed, to direct the inlet air source, etc.

The first caveat is that I want to do all this using the original wiring which has only four wires leading to the rear unit and possibly only two of those actually come from the control panel. That is, I am expecting that one will be for power to the trunk unit's processor and through it, the fans and servos, and the other wire will be what is left for sending any control signals to the back.

The other caveat is that it must be able to run on either 6v positive ground or 12v negative ground.

Ultimately I'll have to hire an engineer to assist in designing the controls (I hope it can be someone who loves old cars and can work on a budget - yes, I know I'm dreaming) so what I am asking here is, is doing something like this even possible whether on a budget or even otherwise?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to ask for help on a group dedicated to those cars, askitg if anyone there knows electronics. This site is for asking specific tech questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I have long ago put out feelers to groups for this type of car but no one there has the expertise, or at least no one with it came forward. When I know what specific questions to ask, I’ll revise my question with them but needed to know first where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want three knobs and some switches to control a fan, and to direct the inlet air source.  That's easy enough for a microcontroller if the interfaces exist.

You'll need a motor-control interface to control the fan, and if I understand, some mechatronics will be required to control the inlet-air-source.  It would be nice to understand how this can be motorized or solenoid driven.

MCUs typically run at 3.3v or 5v, so you'll need to regulate that down from 12v and filter it appropriately.  The power-supply for the drive electronics for (fan and inlet control motor) will depend on their specifics, but will likely include digital (PWM) outputs driving an h-bridge as is common in motor control applications.

If you want to proceed with it, I suggest you document the system clearly, focusing on its inputs (knobs and switches) and its outputs (the fan and air inlet control motor).  Also describe all the expected behaviors.  Such documentation will help you greatly when working with others.

To program and test this you would likely want to build a desktop development rig with duplicate controls, fan, air-intake control system and drive electronics.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really expected to get a lot of flack over this odd question but instead everyone has been helpful. Your advice is excellent too and I had planned on doing as you suggested, probably starting with some kind of block diagram and take it from there. I have not yet determined what will open and close the dampers (on original units, one must climb into the back seat and pull a knob on the parcel shelf!) so that must be determined but all I have are the original blueprints so far. Thank you again and once I have more details worked out, I’ll post if that is the thing to do.